# Site.com: How does one discard unpublished page changes?

Tags: salesforce

I have made some changes to a page within Salesforce's Site.com platform. I never published these changes, and now I want to discard them. Is there a way to do this? It seems basic enough, but I can't find any documentation implying such a functionality exists in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time and research, I've determined that this is, in fact, not a thing.

Comment: ive never used SalesForce site.com, but maybe certain other keywords of interest ('revert' brought up some 'deployment' reversion of changes, not sure if that exactly what your looking for though): https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTFederatedSearchResults#q=revert&t=TopResultTab&sort=relevancy&f:@sflanguage=[en_US]. Also, if you are sure this is solved, then please self-accept your answer (i think you can still edit it later if needed)